# google-calendar-api with java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am developing a java Springboot web application. In Which I have multiple users that login with a adress mail and a password. The login is Ok.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/error.xhtml").permitAll().antMatchers("/error-404.xhtml").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.xhtml");
    ;
    // login
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error=1");
    // logout
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true);

    http.csrf().disable();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

I don’t want a google login. I need to integrate their google calendar to application account so hey cant creat  event and meeting using their gmail id.

Is there any way that I can integrate their google account to the application by having to get consent from the users just only one time in the setting.

[image]

Comment: No. If you want access to a user's Google calendar, they will always have to go through some kind of Google authentication to give you access. You don't have to use that as your application's login, of course, but they do have to do it.

Comment: I don't think so, because I have already used a web application in the past where I had to integrate my Google account just once and subsequently each time I create an event in the application it is created automatically in my google calendar

Comment: Yes, that might be possible. But you'd have to gain access to that calendar the first time at least. You'll get a token from Google that allows you to interact with the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [official sample](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java)

```
// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
    .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
    .setAccessType("offline")
    .build();
```

If FileDataStoreFactory is configured properly it will store each users credentials, then you will only need to request access once.

Update:

questions from comments

> 1.how to configured properly the FileDataStoreFactory store each users credentials and and use those of the connected user?

Check the sample below `.authorize("user");` will denote a user and store the creds for that user.

> 2. how to disconect an account?

by either calling the revoke endpoint or deleting their file stored above.  It will force your app to request authorization again.

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception
    {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        // load client secrets
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                new InputStreamReader(BigQueryConsumer.class.getResourceAsStream("/secret.json")));

        // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore}
        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));

        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
                SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(fileDataStoreFactory)
                .build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }
```

Comment: tks! I just tried the sample, it works very well. I had to log into my Google account just the first time. I have two questions:1.how to configured properly the FileDataStoreFactory store each users credentials and and use those of the connected user? 2. how to disconect an account?

Comment: tks! it works well!

Comment: I am working on similar thing (also Spring Boot and following official documentation), but don't get redirected to Google login I just got print in backend: "Please open the following address in your browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=8....."